# How do you run dotnet core unit tests in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: security, asp.net-core, .net-core

Forked the asp.net core Security repo from github (https://github.com/aspnet/Security) and trying to run the tests in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Test but encountering a test discovery error.  What am I doing wrong?

------ Discover test started ------
'1.0.0-*' is not a valid version string.
Parameter name: value
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.9015246) ==========
------ Discover test started ------
'1.0.0-*' is not a valid version string.
Parameter name: value
Discovering tests in 'D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Test\project.json' ["C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test "D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Test\project.json" --output "D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0" --port 60376 --parentProcessId 10464 --no-build]
'test-xunit' returned '-2147450749'.
Discovering tests in 'D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Test\project.json' ["C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test "D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Test\project.json" --output "D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0" --port 60380 --parentProcessId 10464 --no-build]
'test-xunit' returned '-2147450749'.
Discovering tests in 'D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.ChunkingCookieManager.Sources.Test\project.json' ["C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test "D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.ChunkingCookieManager.Sources.Test\project.json" --output "D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.ChunkingCookieManager.Sources.Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0" --port 60387 --parentProcessId 10464 --no-build]
'test-xunit' returned '-2147450749'.
Discovering tests in 'D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.Test\project.json' ["C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test "D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.Test\project.json" --output "D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0" --port 60392 --parentProcessId 10464 --no-build]
'test-xunit' returned '-2147450749'.
Discovering tests in 'D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop.Test\project.json' ["C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test "D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop.Test\project.json" --output "D:\Dev\GitHub\Microsoft\aspnet\Security\test\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop.Test\bin\Debug\net451\win7-x64" --port 60397 --parentProcessId 10464 --no-build]
========== Discover test finished: 6 found (0:00:07.8144699) ==========

Comment: Did you fork the dev branch? It uses .NET Core 1.1 which isn't released. You need the correct nightly build (and the nightly repositories feed) for it

Comment: Tseng.  You are correct.  I had the dev branch.  Switched to the master branch and now Visual Studio is a bit wonky with code errors.  It may be that I have a restored mix of package dependencies from both dev and master branches at this point.  Do you have a recommendation for how to best clear out the downloaded packages from the dev branch?

Comment: Package restore can sometimes be picky. Sometimes it helps to clear the nuget cache (C:\Users\<Username>\.nuget), restart Visual Studio then it will restore the packages. You may receive errors about missing packages which are part of the .NET Core runtime, then another restart should just fix it

Comment: Strange, I had to clear both the packages folder and nuke the security repo folder and re-pull the master branch from git before it work.  Seems to work now.  Thanks Tseng.  I didn't realize the dev branch was the default branch. My bad.